# Get current date in DD-Mon-YYY format in JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I need to get the date format as 'DD-Mon-YYYY' in javascript.
I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27479790/get-current-date-in-dd-mon-yyy-format-in-jquery), and it got marked duplicate to [jQuery date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250244/jquery-date-formatting)

But, the answers provided in the question are  to get the current date in "DD-MM-YYYY" format and not "DD-MON-YYYY".
Secondly, I am not using datepicker plugin.

Can you please help me as if how to get the current date in "DD-Mon-YYYY" format.

Comment: The currently accepted answer is overly complicated. I've edited [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27480577/1269037) that I think answers your question better. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There is no native format in javascript for `DD-Mon-YYYY`.

You will have to put it all together manually.

The answer is inspired from :
[How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date)

```js
// Attaching a new function  toShortFormat()  to any instance of Date() class

Date.prototype.toShortFormat = function() {

    const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr",
                        "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
                        "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    
    const day = this.getDate();
    
    const monthIndex = this.getMonth();
    const monthName = monthNames[monthIndex];
    
    const year = this.getFullYear();
    
    return `${day}-${monthName}-${year}`;  
}

// Now any Date object can be declared 
let anyDate = new Date(1528578000000);

// and it can represent itself in the custom format defined above.
console.log(anyDate.toShortFormat());    // 10-Jun-2018

let today = new Date();
console.log(today.toShortFormat());     // today's date
```

Answer (score 59):

You can use [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) and hunt for a format that's close to DD-mmm-YYYY (hint: 'en-GB'; you just need to replace the spaces with '-').

```js
const date = new Date();
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
  day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric'
}).replace(/ /g, '-');
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: my output format is Dec-11,-2019 which is not expected. please help me out

Comment: @SujathaGirijala did you find a solution?

Comment: @SujathaGirijala that's probably because of the locale you're using. 'en-GB' is used in this example and that should give you DD Mon YYYY. If you use locale 'en-US' you get Mon DD, YYYY.

Comment: Ugh, this returns "12-Sept-2023" for me today. I'm sorry for all the 56 people who upvoted this.

Answer (score 25):

Use the Moment.js library http://momentjs.com/ It will save you a LOT of trouble.

```
moment().format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
```

Comment: It will also [bloat your code a lot](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3376) and is unnecessary when [JavaScript core can solve the problem without libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27480577/1269037).

Comment: Well yes. There is also the excellent `date-fns` library https://date-fns.org. I mean with today's `npm` packages it hardly makes sense to roll your own.

Comment: There are a large number of date libraries, should there be an answer for every one of them? Many are much smaller than moment.js.

Comment: @RobG Indeed there are now, but back in 2014, when I gave this answer, there really wasn't much to play with.

Answer (score 15):

Can be done with `toLocaleDateString`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

```html
<script>
const date = new Date();
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
  day: '2-digit', month: 'short', year: 'numeric'
}).replace(/ /g, '-');
document.write(formattedDate);
</script>
```

Comment: This gives "12-Sept-2023"

Answer (score 4):

I've made a custom date string format function, you can use that.

```
var  getDateString = function(date, format) {
        var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        getPaddedComp = function(comp) {
            return ((parseInt(comp) < 10) ? ('0' + comp) : comp)
        },
        formattedDate = format,
        o = {
            "y+": date.getFullYear(), // year
            "M+": months[date.getMonth()], //month
            "d+": getPaddedComp(date.getDate()), //day
            "h+": getPaddedComp((date.getHours() > 12) ? date.getHours() % 12 : date.getHours()), //hour
             "H+": getPaddedComp(date.getHours()), //hour
            "m+": getPaddedComp(date.getMinutes()), //minute
            "s+": getPaddedComp(date.getSeconds()), //second
            "S+": getPaddedComp(date.getMilliseconds()), //millisecond,
            "b+": (date.getHours() >= 12) ? 'PM' : 'AM'
        };

        for (var k in o) {
            if (new RegExp("(" + k + ")").test(format)) {
                formattedDate = formattedDate.replace(RegExp.$1, o[k]);
            }
        }
        return formattedDate;
    };
```

And now suppose you've :-

```
    var date = "2014-07-12 10:54:11";
```

So to format this date you write:-

```
var formattedDate = getDateString(new Date(date), "d-M-y")
```

Comment: You don't need to roll your own date functions. The Date object already has a [method that does what the OP asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27480577/1269037).

Comment: thanks, answer above doesn`t work in my locale, but yours works fine!

Answer (score 3):

By default, `new Date().toString()` will always return `'Sun Dec 12 2021...'`, so:

```js
d=new Date();
s=d.getDate()+'-'+d.toString().substr(4,3)+'-'+d.getFullYear();

console.log(s);
```

No JQuery needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
const date = new Date();

date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric' }))
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Comment: ...or you could have [improved the existing answer that uses toLocaleDateString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27480577/1269037).

Answer (score 2):

Using the Intl object (or via *toLocaleString*) is somewhat problematic, but it can be made precise using the [*formatToParts* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) and manually putting the parts in order, e.g.

```js
function formatDate(date = new Date()) {
  let {day, month, year} = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    day:'2-digit',
    month: 'short',
    year: 'numeric'
  }).formatToParts(date).reduce((acc, part) => {
    if (part.type != 'literal') {
      acc[part.type] = part.value;
    }
    return acc;
  }, Object.create(null));
  return `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
}

console.log(formatDate());
```

Using *reduce* on the array returned by *formatToParts* trims out the literals and creates an object with named properties that is then assigned to variables and finally formatted.

This function doesn't always work nicely for languages other than English though as the short month name may have punctuation.

Comment: The perfect answer! Rest all answers will produce the result in a different order

Answer (score 1):

the DD-MM-YYYY is just one of the formats. The format of the jquery plugin, is based on this list: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Tested following code in chrome console:

```
test = new Date()
test.format('d-M-Y')
"15-Dec-2014"
```

Comment: yes I understand the date format, but how can I convert current date to dd-mon-yyyy, Eg I want to get current date in 15-Dec-2014, format.

Comment: Normally this should work (tested in console): test = new Date(); test.format('d-M-Y')

Comment: agreed. this would be great but format is not a function

Comment: When executed in console
`TypeError: test.format is not a function
test = new Date()
test.format('d-M-Y');`

Comment: this is JS not Java

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
  #No parameters
  returns a date with this format DD-MM-YYYY
*/
function now()
{
  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth()+1;
  var day = d.getDate();

  var output = (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + "-" 
              + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-'
              + d.getFullYear();

  return output;
}
```

Comment: This is a very low quality answer: please provide explanation of what your code does. Also, this code does not take parameter, but does expect a global variable `d`. Finally, it does not answer OPs question: YYYY/MM/DD is not the same as DD-Mon-YYY that was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Pass data **changeFormate(15/07/2020)**

```
  changeFormate(date) {
let month_names = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
let incomingDateChnge: any = new Date(date);
let incomingDay = incomingDateChnge.getDate();
let incomingMonth = incomingDateChnge.getMonth();

let incomingYear = incomingDateChnge.getFullYear();
if (incomingDay < 10) {
  incomingDay = '0' + incomingDay;
}

incomingDateChnge = incomingDay + ' ' + month_names[incomingMonth] + ' ' + incomingYear;
return incomingDateChnge;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution, using TypeScript:

```
  convertDateStringToDate(dateStr) {
    //  Convert a string like '2020-10-04T00:00:00' into '4/Oct/2020'
    let months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    let date = new Date(dateStr);
    let str = date.getDate()
                + '/' + months[date.getMonth()]
                + '/' + date.getFullYear()
    return str;
  }
```

(Yeah, I know the question was about JavaScript, but I'm sure I won't be the only Angular developer coming across this article !)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const date = new Date();
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
  day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric'
});
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OP wanted `DD-Mon-YYYY`, your answer is `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var currDate= new Date();
var newDate=currDate.toLocaleDateString();
var splitNewDate= newDate.split('/');
var formatDate= splitNewDate[1] + '-'+ monthNames[splitNewDate[0]] +'-'+ splitNewDate[2];

console.log(formatDate);
```

```
//convert DateTime result in jquery mvc 5 using entity fremwork 

const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    

function DateAndTime(date) {
 
    var value = new Date
        (
        parseInt(date.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, ''))
    ); 
    var dat = value.getDate() +
        "-" +
        monthNames[value.getMonth()] +
        "-" +
        value.getFullYear();

    var hours = value.getHours();
    var minutes = value.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
    return { Date: dat, Time: strTime };
}
// var getdate = DateAndTime(StartDate);
//var Date = getdate.Date;//here get date
//var time = getdate.Time;//here get Time
//alert(Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
function dateFormat(D) {
  const monthNames = [
    'Jan',
    'Feb',
    'Mar',
    'Apr',
    'May',
    'Jun',
    'Jul',
    'Aug',
    'Sep',
    'Oct',
    'Nov',
    'Dec',
  ];

  const day = D.getDate();

  const monthIndex = D.getMonth();
  const monthName = monthNames[monthIndex];

  const year = D.getFullYear();

  return `${day}-${monthName}-${year}`;
}

// Write Javascript code!
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>JS ${dateFormat(new Date('2023-07-05'))}</h1>`;
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var date = new Date();

console.log(date.toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(new RegExp("-", 'g'),"/" ).split("/").reverse().join("/")+" "+date.toJSON().slice(11,19));
```

// output :  01/09/2016 18:30:00

Answer (score -2):

```js
            var today = new Date();           

            var formattedtoday = today.getDate() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getFullYear();
            
            alert(formattedtoday);
```

Comment: This answer does not meet the requirement of the OP. The required format is dd-Mon-yyyy not dd-MM-yyyy

Answer (score -7):

Use date format **dd-MM-yy** . It will output like: 16-December-2014.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please post a valid applicable answer