# How to convert yyyy-mm-dd to dd-Mon-yyyy (with month name) using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, date

I have a date format as 2016-01-09.Now I want to convert this date format in to 09-Jan-2016  I was able to convert in to 09-01-2016.But how can i  get the month name added there.can someone help..
Here is the code which iam trying

```
function formatDate(input){
            var datePart = input.match(/\d+/g),
            year = datePart[0].substring(0,4), // get only two digits
            month = datePart[1], day = datePart[2];

            return day+'-'+month+'-'+year;
}
formatDate ('2010-01-18'); // "18-01-2010"
```

Comment: Try with the link below if you want to use only plain javascript [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480262/get-current-date-in-dd-mon-yyy-format-in-javascript-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480262/get-current-date-in-dd-mon-yyy-format-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```js
function formatDate(d) 
        {
          var date = new Date(d);

         if ( isNaN( date .getTime() ) ) 
         {
            return d;
         }
         else
        {
          
          var month = new Array();
          month[0] = "Jan";
          month[1] = "Feb";
          month[2] = "Mar";
          month[3] = "Apr";
          month[4] = "May";
          month[5] = "Jun";
          month[6] = "Jul";
          month[7] = "Aug";
          month[8] = "Sept";
          month[9] = "Oct";
          month[10] = "Nov";
          month[11] = "Dec";

          day = date.getDate();
          
          if(day < 10)
          {
             day = "0"+day;
          }
          
          return    day  + " " +month[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear();
          }
            
         }


date_response = formatDate('2016-10-25');

alert(date_response)
```

Comment: Why you have use so many lines to create simple array. You can do simply it as var month=["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

Comment: yeah i know but i just coppied that array

Comment: i have not seen yours . My Connection was slow therefor i was not able to post

Comment: @IññoceñtÙšmâñ .your approach works in my case..But for day it is giving only single digit eg..for 2016-10-09 it is giving as 9-OCT-2016..How can I get 0 added before

Comment: @IññoceñtÙšmâñ can u help me in this?

Comment: Thanks @IññoceñtÙšmâñ ..One last ..I dont want to pass the date to this function if the date is already in the required format of DD-MON-YYYY..What should be the condition i should give here...Since here every date is getting called to that function and if the date is already in correct format im getting error

Comment: If you do not want to pass the date to this function then you do not need to call this function . If You want to call this function then you have to pass the date

Comment: @IññoceñtÙšmâñ..The problem here is the dates will come dynamically..I dont have the control to call the function one by one..So I want to validate the date before calling function if the date is correct will not call else will call..So how to give condition

Comment: sometimes the date will already be in correct way eg..01-Jan-2016 ..In that case it gives NaN-undefined..So here the date is in correct format,So that i wont call the function..so how can i check this condition..Thanks imp one plz

Comment: what is that getTime()?

Comment: Return the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 for the given date

Comment: What if other way I want to pass only few which are not in correct format ..Most are in DD-MON-YYYY..Some are in YYYY-MM-DD...In this case i get undefined error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127086/discussion-between-innocent-usman-and-h-varma).

Answer (score 8):

You can do this in multiple ways as follows:

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

function dateFormat(d){
  var t = new Date(d);
  return t.getDate()+'-'+monthNames[t.getMonth()]+'-'+t.getFullYear();
}
```

OR

You can get month in this way:

```
var objDate = new Date(date).toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" });//January
var objDate = new Date(date).toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "short" }); //Jan
```

OR

You can use moment.js

```
var shortMonthName = moment(date).format('MMM') // Jan
var fullMonthName = moment(date).format('MMMM') // January
```

Refer:http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks @chandana Kumara..for many alternatives..your first approach works in my case..But for day it is giving only single digit eg..for 2016-10-09 it is giving as 9-OCT-2016..How can I get 0 added before

Comment: Also if the date is in the format i require i dont want to pass to this function.So how can i write the condition that date is in correct format DD-MON-YYYY...Thanks

Comment: can u help in this?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to use a 3rd party library, e.g. [momenentjs](http://momentjs.com/) (`npm install moment`). You can of course roll it yourself, but the moment/Date format commands are very expressive/powerful. They also support duration and datetime conversions out of the box.

```
 >>> var moment = require('moment')
 >>> moment('2016-01-09').format('DD-MM-YY')
 '09-01-16'
```

Comment: is this all you do? promote momentjs?

Comment: Can also use Date built-in with more work. My argument is that unless there is a a *compelling* reason, there is simply no point in rolling time/date conversions yourself when there are lightweight 3rd party libs available. Keep it DRY / don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: something such as this doesn't require a 3rd party library (no matter how `lightweight`). It's literally 3 or 4 lines of JavaScript. As Chandana Kumara has already shown

Comment: Yet @Chandana Kumara still presents the momentjs option (props, but add the full solution of 'DD-MM-YY'). 3-4 lines of stackoverflow will *work* for dev, but are brittle for prod.

Comment: yeah, after all of the other options (which work, btw). tell me how they are brittle, exactly?