# Convert datetime format in string to date javascript?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

Let say I have an object `product`

I can use `product.createdDate` to get `2018-04-16 15:12:46.179427` or any other date with the same format.

how do I convert to date in javascript so I and show it as `16 April 2018`?

I'm using angularjs.

I tried `{{product.createdDate | date : 'dd MM, yyyy'}}`but it show `2018-04-16 15:12:46.179427`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to do it. You can find your answer in a similar question here :

[Get current date in DD-Mon-YYY format in JavaScript/Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480262/get-current-date-in-dd-mon-yyy-format-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can use date pipe to filter it out

html

```
<p>
  {{date | date:'dd MMMM yyyy'}}
</p>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.date = new Date("2018-04-16 15:12:46.179427");
```

To get directly in controller inject **$filter**

```
var date = $filter('date')(new Date("2018-04-16 15:12:46.179427"), 'dd MMMM yyyy');

console.log(date); // 16 April 2018
```

Please refer the demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-ifmbji?file=home%2Fhome.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```js
var date = new Date("2018-04-16 15:12:46.179427".replace(/-/g,"/"));
var d = moment(date).format('D MMMM  YYYY')
console.log(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert this date using javascript you have to define the months like bellow.

```
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

const date = new Date('2018-04-16 15:12:46.179427');
const formatedDate = date.getDate() + ' ' + months[date.getMonth()] +' '+ date.getFullYear();
```

But if you only want to show it in the UI, use a pipe to convert it.