# Format date in react.js from data in api url

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to format my date in React/ typescript project, however the data is from an api, so I can map over the data and display it but how do I convert it to a format like '22 June 2021'?

The data from the api is in format:

```
{
   "title": 'First',
   "time": "2020-07-22T13:22:10.2566789+00:00", 
}
```

Then I am binding to the template as `{data.time}`

Any idea's?

Comment: You can use libraries like `dayjs` to convert date.

Comment: is there a way using vanilla js?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480262/get-current-date-in-dd-mon-yyy-format-in-javascript-jquery/27480352

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a simple way to achieve that

```js
const date = new Date("2020-07-22T13:22:10.2566789+00:00")
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", {
  day: "numeric",
  month: "long",
  year: "numeric"
})

console.log(formattedDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

> PackageName: npm i moment

Install the moment npm.
"moment" is an npm package. After installation import the package
import moment from 'moment'
Next, Convert the data like this:

```
"time": "2020-07-22T13:22:10.2566789+00:00"
moment(time).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```

Comment: Great addition to mention a library. It would be helpful to include the full npm install command,

Answer (score 0):

For Example, if your code is like this:

```
var objName = {
   "title": 'First',
   "time": "2020-07-22T13:22:10.2566789+00:00", 
}
```

This is how you can implement the new Time Format (Dont forget to npm install and import moment.js)

```
let formattedTime = moment(objName.time).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');

console.log(formattedTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

DateFns it is a light library, so I can recommend it.

```
import format from 'date-fns/format'

const formattedDate = format(
  new Date('2020-07-22T13:22:10.2566789+00:00'),
  'dd MMMM yyyy'
)

console.log(formattedDate)
```