# How to convert format date to dd/mm

Tags: javascript, date

Heloo, i want to convert format date `2022-04-09 08:00:33` to format `9 April`. i was trying to convert it, but the format still wrong, thanks for help me before

#solved

Comment: Probably this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27480577/10117515

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to date manipulation in JavaScript, there are a lot of third-party libraries available. Some of the most popular options are [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and [Day.js](https://day.js.org/). When it comes to formatting a date into a custom format, these libraries are really easy to use.

Example:

```
moment('2022-04-09 08:00:33','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('D MMMM')
```

converts:

> 2022-04-09 08:00:33 to 9 April

You can visit the [link](https://momentjs.com/) to see available formats.

Or You can use a simple solution that involves native date class:

```js
const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-gb', {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
  });
  console.log(date)
```

but for this input date should be in proper date format i.e., ISO String of timestamp in milliseconds.

The arrangement of day and month will be according to locale you use.

Comment: thank youu, but i dont want to use library

Comment: check the edit@MuhammadZulfanWahyudin

Answer (score 0):

```
export const formatDate = (date) => {
  const newDate = new Date(date)
  const month = newDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })
  const day = newDate.getDate()
  const formated = `${day} ${month}`
  return formated
}
```